# Warnings when trying to integrate linkedin-sdk for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, linkedin-api

I am getting these warnings when trying to integrate linkedin-sdk into my project:

(Xcode 7.3.1)

```
while processing /Users/<user>/workspace/<app>/ios/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/Foundation-3VLEO83GYRX3B.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static libraries.
while processing /Users/<user>/workspace/<app>/ios/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/ObjectiveC-32FFDQ4QB6N1Y.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/<user>/workspace/<app>/ios/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/Darwin-24ADG18KIJ6C5.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/<user>/workspace/<app>/ios/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKSessionManager.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/UIKit-183QWGUEZ8AOT.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/<user>/workspace/<app>/ios/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKUtils.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/CoreFoundation-39RL94RHQHDI3.pcm: No such file or directory
```

Even when building the sampleapp that comes with the SDK, I am getting the same warnings:

```
while processing /Users/<user>/Desktop/li-ios-sdk/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/Foundation-3VLEO83GYRX3B.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static libraries.
while processing /Users/<user>/Desktop/li-ios-sdk/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/ObjectiveC-32FFDQ4QB6N1Y.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/<user>/Desktop/li-ios-sdk/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/Darwin-24ADG18KIJ6C5.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/<user>/Desktop/li-ios-sdk/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKSessionManager.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/UIKit-183QWGUEZ8AOT.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/<user>/Desktop/li-ios-sdk/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKUtils.o):
warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/3BZQQ619QJV49/CoreFoundation-39RL94RHQHDI3.pcm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I was able to suppress those during debug builds by wrapping linkedin-sdk with own framework. In archive they do appear anyways, though.